# Sent message appear in calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar

I want to create app that can send event message via gmail to another user. After getting message event should be set in calendar.How can i do that?

---

Comment: coding and some more coding.

Comment: If I had the code, I would have written. I only want to know can i do that

Comment: @Arthurghev `I only want to know can i do that` It's possible, but for us to know if _you_ can do it, we need to know more about you.